# AttributeError at /admin/accounts/school/ 'School' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

hello am just wondering why cant I return `return f'{self.user.username} Profile'`
form this model

```python
class School(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    logo = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='logos')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

what should be the syntax here help

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing int instead of User object. Int doesn't have field `username`. If you want to create Many-to-one relation in Django you should use `ForeignKey. Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Change your class to:

```py
class School(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    logo = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='logos')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```